# Get day of month of timestamp in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, date, timestamp

Is there any operation of mongodb that I could use to retrieve the day of the month out of a timestamp, inside an aggregation?

I would like to do something like this:

```
{"$dayOfMonth" : "$timestamp"}
```

If not possible, what would be the best way to convert "$timestamp" into mongodb date format?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a [$dayOfMonth](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dayOfMonth/#exp._S_dayOfMonth) aggregation operator.

```
db.blah.insert({ts:new Date("2014-02-01")})
db.blah.aggregate([{$project:{dayOfMonth:{$dayOfMonth:"$ts"}}}])
```

Comment: He didn't make it clear but I happen to know from an earlier question by the OP that he mean "epoch timestamp" rather than a date object